# Replace text in the first line in a huge txt tab delimited file

Tags: python, perl, file, vbscript

I have a huge text file (19GB in size); it is a genetic  data file with variables and observations.
The first line contains the variable names and they are structured as followed:

```
id1.var1 id1.var2 id1.var3 id2.var1 id2.var2 id2.var3
```

I need to swap id1, id2 ect. with corresponding values that are in another text file (this file has about 7k rows) ids are not in any particular order and it's structured as follow:

```
oldId newIds
id1 rs004
id2 rs135
```

I have done some google search and could not really find a language that would allow to do the following:

1. read the first line
2. replace the ids with the new ids
3. remove the first line from the original file and replace it with the new one

Is this a good approach or is there a better one?
Which is the best language to accomplish this?
We have people with experience in python, vbscipt and Perl.

Answer (score 4):

The whole "replace" thing is possible in almost any language (I'm sure about Python and Perl), as long as *the length of the replacement line is the same as the original*, or if it can be *made* the same by padding with whitespace (otherwise, you'll have to rewrite the whole file).

Open the file for reading and writing (`w+` mode), read the first line, prepare the new line, `seek` to position 0 in the file, write the new line, close the file.

Comment: It might not work if "id1" => "rs004". So there might be the only way to write new file.

Comment: Thank you. I am running a Python code right now that does what you suggested. The ids are not the same length and the file needs to be rewritten. I am in a windows environment and it could take hours to run. I hope it works.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you use the [`Tie::File`](https://metacpan.org/module/Tie%3a%3aFile) module, which maps the lines in a text file to a Perl array and will make the rewriting of the lines after the header a simple job.

This program demonstrates. It first reads all of the old/new IDs into a hash, and then maps the data file using `Tie::File`. The first line of the file (in `$file[0]`) is modified using a substitution, and then the array is untied to rewrite and close the file.

You will need to change your file names from the ones I have used. Also beware that I have assumed that the IDs are always "word" characters (alphanumeric plus underscore) followed by a dot, and have no spaces. Of course you will want to back up your file before you modify it, and you should test the program on a smaller file before you update the real thing.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Tie::File;

my %ids;
open my $fh, '<', 'newids.txt' or die $!;
while (<$fh>) {
  my ($old, $new) = split;
  $ids{$old} = $new;
}

tie my @file, 'Tie::File', 'datafile.txt' or die $!;
$file[0] =~ s<(\w+)(?=\.)><$ids{$1} // $1>eg;
untie @file;
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be pretty easy.  I would use Python as I am a Python fan.  Outline:

- Read the mapping file, and save the mapping (in Python, use a dictionary).
- Read the data file a line at a time, remap variable names, and output the edited line.

You really can't edit a file in-place... hmm, I guess you could if every new variable name was always exactly the same length as the old name.  But for ease of programming, and safety while running, it would be best to always write a new output file and then delete the original.  This means you will need at least 20 GB of free disk space before running this, but that shouldn't be a problem.

Here is a Python program that shows how to do it.  I used your example data to make test files and this seems to work.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import re
import sys

try:
    fname_idmap, fname_in, fname_out = sys.argv[1:]
except ValueError:
    print("Usage: remap_ids <id_map_file> <input_file> <output_file>")
    sys.exit(1)

# pattern to match an ID, only as a complete word (do not match inside another id)
# match start of line or whitespace, then match non-period until a period is seen
pat_id = re.compile("(^|\s)([^.]+).")

idmap = {}

def remap_id(m):
    before_word = m.group(1)
    word = m.group(2)
    if word in idmap:
        return before_word + idmap[word] + "."
    else:
        return m.group(0)  # return full matched string unchanged

def replace_ids(line, idmap):
    return re.sub(pat_id, remap_id, line)

with open(fname_idmap, "r") as f:
    next(f)  # discard first line with column header: "oldId newIds"
    for line in f:
        key, value = line.split()
        idmap[key] = value

with open(fname_in, "r") as f_in, open(fname_out, "w") as f_out:
    for line in f_in:
        line = replace_ids(line, idmap)
        f_out.write(line)
```

Comment: thank you so much! I'll show this code to my programmer. Thanks